# How do you stop a timer for a function?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import random
from random import randint

#screen setup
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=450, height=450)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(3)
#user
player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.color("green")
player.penup()
#First enemy
player2 = Turtle()
player2.color("green")
player2.shape('turtle')
player2.penup()
player2.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player2.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
#Second enemy
player3 = Turtle()
player3.color("green")
player3.shape('square')
player3.penup()
player3.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player3.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
#third enemy
player4 = Turtle()
player4.color("green")
player4.shape('triangle')
player4.penup()
player4.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player4.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
score_board = Turtle()
score_board.pu()
score_board.color("yellow")
score_board.hideturtle()
score_board.goto(0,160)

end_turtle = Turtle()
end_turtle.color("pink")
end_turtle.pu()
end_turtle.hideturtle()
end_turtle.goto(0,200)



score_num= Turtle()
score_num.pu()
score_num.color("yellow")
score_num.pu()
score_num.hideturtle()
score_num.goto(0,150)


#earth

earth = Turtle()
earth.penup()
earth.shape("circle")
earth.color("blue")
earth.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5.6, stretch_len = 5.6)
earth.setpos(150,-150)

#bullet
bullet = Turtle()
bullet.shape("turtle")
bullet.color("purple")
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.penup()
bullet.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.penup()
px = 0
py = 0

def up():
    global px
    global py
    py = player.ycor() + 5

    if py >= 200:
        py -= 15

    player.sety(py)

def down():
    global px
    global py
    py = player.ycor() - 5

    if py < -200:
        py += 15

    player.sety(py)

def left():
    global px
    global py
    px = player.xcor() - 5

    if px <= -200:
        px += 15

    player.setx(px)

def right():
    global px
    global py
    px = player.xcor() + 5

    if px >= 200:
        px -= 15 

    player.setx(px)




#distance calculator
def checkcollision(t1, t2):
    while t1.distance(t2) < 10:
        t2.setpos(randint(-100, 100), randint(-100, 100))

# the x and y distance that the player2 turtle moves 
dx = 5
dy = 5

earth_health = 100

def checkbullet(bullet,turtle):
    while bullet.distance(turtle) < 10:
        turtle.hideturtle()
count = 0
def check_earth(planet,turtle):
    global earth_health
    global count
    if planet.distance(turtle)<40:
        if count>1:
            score_num.clear()
        turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))

        earth_health+=-10
        score_board.write("Earth health")

        score_num.write(earth_health)
        count+=1

        if earth_health<90:
            end_turtle.write("You lost and humanity lost")

##            if planet.distance(turtle_x, turtle_y) > EARTH_RADIUS + CURSOR_SIZE:
##                turtle.setpos(turtle_x,turtle_y)
##                break
##
##            turtle_x = random.randint(-200,200)
##            turtle_y = random.randint(-200,200)
##    global damage
##    while planet.distance(turtle)>10:
##        turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))

#1st enemy(switch heading)
head = 0
def enemy1():
    global earth_health
    if earth_health<90:
        screen.ontimer(enemy1,0)        

    checkcollision(player,player2)
    check_earth(earth,player2)
    global head
    player2.fd(5)

    x2, y2 = player2.position()
    head = player2.heading()

    if y2 <= -200 or y2 >= 200:
        player2.fd(0)
        player2.backward(7.5)
        player2.setheading((head)* -1)

    if x2 <= -200 or x2 >= 200:
        player2.fd(0)
        player2.backward(7.5)
        if head < 90:
            player2.setheading(0 - ((head) * 2))
        if head>90<179:

            player2.setheading((head)/2)

        if head>179<260:
            player2.setheading((head)/3)


        if head>260<361:
            player2.setheading((head)/2)

    screen.ontimer(enemy1,50)

#Second enemy(dx,dy)
def enemy2():
    checkcollision(player, player3)
    check_earth(earth,player3)


    global dx
    global dy
    x3, y3 = player3.position()

    player3.setposition(x3 + dx, y3 + dy)


    if y3 <= -200 or y3 >= 200:
        dy *= -1
        player3.sety(y3 + dy)

    if x3 <= -200 or x3 >= 200:
        dx *= -1
        player3.setx(x3 + dx)


    screen.ontimer(enemy2,50)

def enemy3():
    checkcollision(player,player4)
    check_earth(earth,player4)

    player4.fd(5)
    x4, y4 = player4.position()
    head3 = player4.heading()

    if y4 <= -200 or y4 >= 200:
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.backward(7.5)
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.setheading((head3)* -1)

    if x4 <= -200 or x4 >= 200:
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.backward(7.5)
        player4.fd(0)
        if head3 < 90:
            player4.setheading(0 - ((head3) * 2))
        if head3>90<179:
            player4.setheading((head3)/2)

        if head3>179<260:
            player4.setheading((head3)/3)


        if head3>260<361:
            player4.setheading((head3)/2)
    screen.ontimer(enemy3,50)

#When bullet hits wall   
def bullet_end():
    screen.listen()   
    screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
    screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
    screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
    screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
    screen.onkeyrelease(shoot_key,"w")


def shoot_key():


    bullet.setposition(px,py)
    bullet.shape("circle")
    bullet.showturtle()
    bullet.penup()

    def shoot():
        checkbullet(bullet,player2)
        checkbullet(bullet,player3)
        checkbullet(bullet,player4)
        bx = bullet.xcor()
        by = bullet.ycor()
        bullet.fd(5)
        if bx>=200 or bx<=-200:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.backward(7.5)
            bullet_end()
        if by>=200 or by<=-200:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.backward(7.5)
            bullet_end()

        screen.ontimer(shoot,50)
    shoot()
screen.listen() 
screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
screen.onkeyrelease(shoot_key,"w")



enemy1()
enemy2()
enemy3()
screen.mainloop()
```

The problem lies here:

```
def check_earth(planet,turtle):
        global earth_health
        global count
        if planet.distance(turtle)<40:
            if count>1:
                score_num.clear()
            turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))

            earth_health+=-10
            score_board.write("Earth health")

            score_num.write(earth_health)
            count+=1

            if earth_health<90:
                end_turtle.write("You lost and humanity lost")

                if planet.distance(turtle_x, turtle_y) > EARTH_RADIUS + CURSOR_SIZE:
                    turtle.setpos(turtle_x,turtle_y)
                    break

                turtle_x = random.randint(-200,200)
                turtle_y = random.randint(-200,200)
        global damage
        while planet.distance(turtle)>10:
            turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))

    #1st enemy(switch heading)
    head = 0
    def enemy1():
        global earth_health
        if earth_health<90:
            screen.ontimer(enemy1,0)
```

At first the enemy1 function runs on a timer of 50 milliseconds but when When the earth_health variable is less than than 90 this conditional should make the enemy1 function stop running as i set it its timer to 0. Instead the entire program crashes which in a sense is ok relating to my goals with this program but how could I make the enemy1 function stop running its loop on the conditional rather than the entire program?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional statement to see if it should stop running -- if it is you can use "return" with no value. That will breakout of the function.

In the beginning set some value (global)

```
global enemy1stop
enemy1stop = False
```

In the check_earth function:

```
def check_earth(planet,turtle):
        global earth_health
        global count
        if planet.distance(turtle)<40:
            if count>1:
                score_num.clear()
            turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))

            earth_health+=-10
            score_board.write("Earth health")

            score_num.write(earth_health)
            count+=1

            if earth_health<90:
                end_turtle.write("You lost and humanity lost")

                if planet.distance(turtle_x, turtle_y) > EARTH_RADIUS + CURSOR_SIZE:
                    turtle.setpos(turtle_x,turtle_y)
                    break

                turtle_x = random.randint(-200,200)
                turtle_y = random.randint(-200,200)
        global damage
        while planet.distance(turtle)>10:
            turtle.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))

    #1st enemy(switch heading)
    head = 0
    def enemy1():
        global earth_health
        if earth_health<90:  
            enemy1stop=True  # <--
```

And in the enemy1 function:

```
def enemy1():
    global earth_health
    if earth_health<90:
        screen.ontimer(enemy1,0)        

    ...

    if enemy1stop == True:
        return # this will stop the function from repeating

    screen.ontimer(enemy1,50)
```